# Implement BiLSTM-CRF for NER task Using Deprecated Frameworks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I've been trying to build a BiLSTM-CRF model for a Named Entity Recognition task, for which, obviously, I've been using TensorFlow 2.16 and Keras 3.0. However, while trying to implement a CRF layer using deprecated keras_contrib or the tensorflow_addons GitHub resources. I've been running into a myriad of issues as these frameworks might not be compatible with the latest TF and Keras versions. However, I'm unwilling to downgrade to a lower version of TF just for this task. Are there any suitable alternatives present that I can use for accomplishing my task?

Added the code below.

```
from keras.layers import Embedding, SimpleRNN, Dense, LSTM, GRU, Bidirectional, TimeDistributed, Input
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF
from keras_contrib.losses import crf_loss
from keras_contrib.metrics import crf_accuracy 
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import keras


optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
input = Input(shape=(max_length,))
model= Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dimension, embeddings_initializer="uniform", trainable=False)(input)
model= LSTM(360, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal())(model)
model= Bidirectional(LSTM(180, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()))(model)
model= TimeDistributed(Dense(27, activation='relu'))(model)
crf = CRF(units=27, sparse_target=True)
out = crf(model)
model = keras.Model(input, out)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=crf_loss, metrics=[crf_accuracy, 'accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                    ┃ Output Shape           ┃       Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ input_layer (InputLayer)        │ (None, 78)             │             0 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ embedding (Embedding)           │ (None, 78, 300)        │     5,727,000 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ lstm (LSTM)                     │ (None, 78, 360)        │       951,840 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ bidirectional (Bidirectional)   │ (None, 78, 360)        │       779,040 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ time_distributed                │ (None, 78, 27)         │         9,747 │
│ (TimeDistributed)               │                        │               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ crf (CRF)                       │ (None, 78, 27)         │         1,539 │
└─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────┘


 Total params: 7,469,166 (28.49 MB)
 Trainable params: 7,469,166 (28.49 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
**
```

```
history = model.fit(
    train_text,train_labels,
    validation_data=(val_text, val_labels),
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=32,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[MacroF1Callback((val_text, val_labels), (train_text, train_labels))]
)
```

Output:

```
----> 7 history = model.fit(
      8     train_text,train_labels,
      9     validation_data=(val_text, val_labels),

c:\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    121             # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122             # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124         finally:
    125             del filtered_tb

c:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras_contrib\layers\crf.py in call(self, X, mask)
    290 
    291         if self.test_mode == 'viterbi':
--> 292             test_output = self.viterbi_decoding(X, mask)
    293         else:
    294             test_output = self.get_marginal_prob(X, mask)

c:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras_contrib\layers\crf.py in viterbi_decoding(self, X, mask)
    557 
...
**module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'dot'**

Arguments received by CRF.call():
  • X=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 78, 27), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
```